# Timeseries database with concurrent update of historical data

Tags: database, time-series, updates, atomic

I need to store timeseries data, and have special requirements. Lets say that I want to store the turnover for my business for every 5 minute-interval. E.g one timeseries

```
Store#1
1/12–2016 10:00–10:05: 100$
1/12–2016 10:05–10:10: 50$
…
```

And another timeseries

```
Store#2
1/12–2016 10:00–10:05: 10$
1/12–2016 10:05–10:10: 30$
…
```

I get a feed of data telling when something was sold and in which store. E.g

```
Store#1,10:02:40,5$
```

For every such feed-event I want to update the database. For the feed-event example above, it would be

```
db.series("Store#1").update(1/12–2016 10:00–10:05, add: 5$)
```

I may get this feed-event much later then 1/12–2016 10:05, so I want to be able to update “historical data”.

There are lots of TSDB’s out there, but I have a hard time finding one that fulfill my needs. Especially

- Being able to update historical data. It seems like a lot of the TSDB’s are very focused on new data is always essentially: now,final-value
- Being able to update atomically, or using some kind of locking. Two threads may get an feed-event about a sale belonging in the same 5-minute interval, and they need to be able to add to the stored value without risking to overwrite (cancel out) what the other thread added.

It would be great if the TSDB could be operated from java.

Can anyone point out a TSDB that supports updating historical data with concurrency control?

Comment: Not seeing anything here that can't be done in a standard RDBMS; SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres; take your pick.

Comment: I agree, it can be done using any general-purpose database. But there is a reason special databases were created for time-series data. They are (potentially) better at handling this kind of data - performing better, easier to query knowing the structure of data, aggregation, easy integration with UI tools (e.g. showing a graph), etc. etc. But we will definitely fall back on using a custom general purpose database, if there is not a TSDB fitting our needs. Just exploring my options.

Answer (score 1):

Most timeseries metrics databases are like log oriented and not meant for transactional usage. Most won't ever provide ACID compliance for which it's better to use MySQL and PostgreSQL like databases.

Sidewinder does satisfy your requirement 2 i.e. it's thread safe
https://github.com/srotya/sidewinder